# drupal 8 - "enabled module does not appear in module list"

Tags: module, datatables, drupal-8

I have installed Drupal 8.1. under Ubuntu 14.04.
As i have no FTP installed there, i unpack  modules manually
in the modules folder (currently set to 777).
I've installed several modules with no issue, 
but after installing module "Datatables (Version 8.x-1.0-alpha1+1-dev) 
it will not show up in the module list in the backend.
Cache is rebuilt, i've repeatet module installation (via drush
enabling) several times successfully, still it won't show up.
Any ideas ?

Regards,
Tobias

Comment: Same behaviour with module version 8.x-1.x-dev

Comment: Tested on my dev environment (D8.1.7 + also Ubuntu 14.04) - it works just expected, module is listed among all other modules on admin/modules page. So problem is not with this specific module, probably...

Answer (score 0):

Why would you manually unpack modules? The best way to download/install a module is just by using Drush.

You can do this by going to the specific module page (For example: https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and taking it's name. The name is right after the /project/ so in this case it would be "views".

You can now either download it using Drush with

```
drush dl views -y
```

Or you can download AND enable it with

```
drush en views -y
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for late response - holiday issues. In fact, i've already downloaded and enabled the module with drush, returning a "module enabled" status from drush. refreshed cache, but still it does not show up in backend ...

Answer (score 0):

Good News everyone - after my holidays the module does show up - without any action from my side... ;-)
Issue can be closed.